# Improve slow performance using sequelize when doing upsert on thousands of records to Azure SQL Database

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

Experiencing slow performance when syncing a link table using upsert with a compound key on `mssql` compared to `mysql`.

When running this on `mysql` syncing 14000 records it takes about 0.7 minutes, where as syncing to the Azure DB using `mssql` takes 21 minutes.

Here is my Schema:

```
    students_groups: this.sequelize.define(
        'students_groups',
        students_groups: {
            student: Sequelize.STRING(24),
            group: Sequelize.STRING(24),
            active: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        },
        {
            timestamps: true,
            createdAt: 'created_at',
            updatedAt: 'updated_at',
            indexes: [
                {
                    fields: ['student'],
                },
                {
                    fields: ['group'],
                },
                {
                    fields: ['student', 'group'],
                    unique: true
                }
            ],
        }
    )
```

This is the loop

```
    await this.SQLSchemas['students_groups'].sync().then(async () => {
        for(let record of records) {
            const where: any = {};
            where['student'] = '123456789123';
            where['group'] = '234567891234';
            await this.SQLSchemas['students_groups'].upsert(
                record,
                {
                    where: where
                }
            );
        }
    });
```

Example record:

```
    {
        student: '123456789123',
        group: '234567891234',
        active: 1
    }
```

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links. RAM size of your MySQL Host server Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; for MySQL server tuning analysis to improve your MySQL even more.  The AZURE mssql tuning will be best addressed by someone else.